# Why am I seeing this in the terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, bashrc

I have installed miniconda, psi4 some days ago. But I have found them not so interesting. So I uninstalled them. But after that, I am seeing this 
`` bash: export: `PATH-/home/soumyadip/miniconda/bin:/home/soumyadip/psi4conda/bin:/home/soumyadip/Downloads/bashrc/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin': not a valid identifier ``
at the very top of the terminal each time. Is it a problem? How to remove it and how can I check that my system is okay?

Comment: Don't worry, your system is fine. These are just dangling entries in your path. It's probably not going to be easy to find out where this is being set, but I'd start checking your `.profile` and `.bashrc` files.

Answer (score 2):

That looks entirely like a typo of a dash for an equals-sign; instead of:

```
PATH-/home/soumyadip/miniconda/bin...
```

You want:

```
PATH=/home/soumyadip/miniconda/bin...
    \---- this character changed
```

Beyond that, it appears that the removal process did not remove everything it installed. You might consider removing the `/home/soumyadip/miniconda/bin:/home/soumyadip/psi4conda/bin` section from your .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

Idea: There exist backup copies of .bashrc, .profile etc. in /etc/skel/. So one could replace a corrupt .bashrc simply by overwitting from there.

Caution: if you replace the .bashrc file with a fresh one, it will remove any other modification(s) you have made to it. For example, one could add aliases, custom function or PATH in .bashrc. When you replace the file, all those modifications will be lost. Better you can keep a copy of your modified .bashrc before replacing it. Later, you can carefully extract the required part from it. To keep a backup copy of your modified .bashrc in your home directory with name my_bashrc use the following in a terminal,

```
/bin/cp ~/.bashrc ~/my_bashrc
```

Why /bin/cp: In case if you have messed with your $PATH variable when changed ~/.bashrc all the executable will be unavailable from your terminal and cp will not work anymore. So it is recommended to call cp with its full path as /bin/cp while you are trying to copy something with corrupt ~/.bashrc.

Finally, use the following command in your terminal to replace the ~/.bashrc with a fresh copy,

```
/bin/cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

It will replace your corrupt ~/.bashrc with a fresh one. After that, you need to source the ~/.bashrc so that the change takes place immediately, write in the terminal,

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

or,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or, if that does not work you can close the terminal and open it again.